# Remove variation in Woocommerce cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a pizza with multiple ingredients. If the user ticks an "Add Ingredients" box the choices come up as drop downs defaulted at "none". I need to get the "none" selected options to hide in the cart and checkout.

I've got them to hide in the cart page but they still show in the masthead cart and the checkout.

Here is some of the code displaying the ingredients:

```html
         <li>Add Ingredients?</li>
    </ul>
</dd> 
<dt class="variation-GreenOlives">Green Olives:</dt>
<dd class="variation-GreenOlives">
    <p>Whole Pizza ($1.00)</p>
</dd>
<dt class="variation-RipeOlives">Ripe Olives:</dt>
<dd class="variation-RipeOlives">
    <p>None</p>
</dd>
<dt class="variation-SlicedTomatoes">Sliced Tomatoes:</dt>
<dd class="variation-SlicedTomatoes">
    <p>None</p>
</dd>
<dt class="variation-FreshMushrooms">Fresh Mushrooms:</dt>
<dd class="variation-FreshMushrooms">
    <p>None</p>
</dd>
<dt class="variation-ArtichokeHearts">Artichoke Hearts:</dt>
<dd class="variation-ArtichokeHearts">
    <p>None</p>
</dd>
<dt class="variation-CannedMushrooms">Canned Mushrooms:</dt>
<dd class="variation-CannedMushrooms">
    <p>None</p>
</dd>
<dt class="variation-FreshBasil">Fresh Basil:</dt>
<dd class="variation-FreshBasil">
    <p>None</p>
</dd>
<dt class="variation-Spinach">Spinach:</dt>
<dd class="variation-Spinach">
    <p>None</p>
</dd>
<dt class="variation-Pepperjack">Pepperjack:</dt>
<dd class="variation-Pepperjack">
    <p>None</p>
</dd>
<dt class="variation-ExtraCheese">Extra Cheese:</dt>
<dd class="variation-ExtraCheese">
    <p>None</p>
</dd>
<dt class="variation-Cheddar">Cheddar:</dt>
<dd class="variation-Cheddar">
    <p>None</p>
</dd>
<dt class="variation-Swiss">Swiss:</dt>
<dd class="variation-Swiss">
    <p>None</p>
</dd>
```

And here is the code that is hiding the "none" options on the cart page:

```js
function hideNone(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("dd>p:contains('None')").hide() && $("dd").prev().hide();
    });
}
```

So even though the code is the same on all three of the places the order shows, this code is only hiding it on the cart page. I'm using woocommerce and gravity forms on a local install. Thanks for your help.

Comment: how are you calling the function?

Comment: I call it in the footer along with a few others.

Comment: try putting this out side the function call.  `$(document).ready(function(){
        $("dd>p:contains('None')").hide() && $("dd").prev().hide();
    });`

Comment: I put that after the call in the footer but it did not change anything. No error either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think is that you have declared the function `hideNone()` and haven't called the function. [`$( document ).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) is actually used for calling a function when the document is loaded, that means that is not need to be a function definition. See  the documentation.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("dd>p:contains('None')").hide() && $("dd").prev().hide();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dt class="variation-GreenOlives">Green Olives:</dt>
<dd class="variation-GreenOlives">
  <p>Whole Pizza ($1.00)</p>
</dd>
<dt class="variation-RipeOlives">Ripe Olives:</dt>
<dd class="variation-RipeOlives">
  <p>None</p>
</dd>
<dt class="variation-SlicedTomatoes">Sliced Tomatoes:</dt>
<dd class="variation-SlicedTomatoes">
  <p>None</p>
</dd>
<dt class="variation-FreshMushrooms">Fresh Mushrooms:</dt>
<dd class="variation-FreshMushrooms">
  <p>None</p>
</dd>
<dt class="variation-ArtichokeHearts">Artichoke Hearts:</dt>
<dd class="variation-ArtichokeHearts">
  <p>None</p>
</dd>
<dt class="variation-CannedMushrooms">Canned Mushrooms:</dt>
<dd class="variation-CannedMushrooms">
  <p>None</p>
</dd>
<dt class="variation-FreshBasil">Fresh Basil:</dt>
<dd class="variation-FreshBasil">
  <p>None</p>
</dd>
<dt class="variation-Spinach">Spinach:</dt>
<dd class="variation-Spinach">
  <p>None</p>
</dd>
<dt class="variation-Pepperjack">Pepperjack:</dt>
<dd class="variation-Pepperjack">
  <p>None</p>
</dd>
<dt class="variation-ExtraCheese">Extra Cheese:</dt>
<dd class="variation-ExtraCheese">
  <p>None</p>
</dd>
<dt class="variation-Cheddar">Cheddar:</dt>
<dd class="variation-Cheddar">
  <p>None</p>
</dd>
<dt class="variation-Swiss">Swiss:</dt>
<dd class="variation-Swiss">
  <p>None</p>
</dd>
```

Comment: This did not work. I think it is a woocommerce function messing this up rather than problems with my js. Ill have to look into the code for the cart and see what displays the variations and alter that code rather than try to override it on my own. Thanks for your help.